# Android Studio Compile the project error

Tags: android

I encounter the following error when I try to compile my project with gradle (the log length exceeds the limit, the following is only part of it):

```
15:53:22.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(anet.channel.SessionCenter$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(anet.channel.strategy.e) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
15:53:22.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
[org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'
15:53:22.482 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
15:53:22.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 215: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
15:53:22.486 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 4 mins 21.866 secs.
15:53:22.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 4 mins 28.755 secs, idle: 0.052 secs
15:53:22.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 215: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
15:53:22.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:53:22.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
15:53:22.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
15:53:22.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:53:22.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
15:53:22.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
15:53:22.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
15:53:22.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
15:53:22.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
15:53:22.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
15:53:22.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:159)
15:53:22.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:146)
15:53:22.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1386)
15:53:22.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:272)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 81 more
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexOutOfProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:206)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 85 more
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexOutOfProcess$1(DexByteCodeConverter.java:196)
15:53:22.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: I did not open it Code obfuscation      minifyEnabled false